# Compute count and running total for date field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, aggregate-functions

Here is my dilemma. I have a field in the SQL database, called `booking_date`. The date is in a format like this

```
2014-10-13 12:05:58.533
```

I would like to be able to compute a count of bookings for each date (not date time) as well as a running total.

So my report would look something like so

[image: count report]

My SQL code is like so

```
SELECT  
   dbo.book.create_time,
   replace(convert(nvarchar, dbo.book.create_time, 106),' ', '/') as bookingcreation,
   count(*) as Book_Count
```

FROM
       ....tables here

However, my count calculation is counting the date based of this type of date format > 2014-10-13 12:05:58.533 which is not computing correctly.

So instead, I'm getting this:

[image: report as is now]

Also, I am not sure how to compute the running total. But I first need to get the count correctly.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL 2008, sorry, not sure where I can edit the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using SQL Server.  To get the count by day:

```
SELECT cast(dbo.book.create_time as date) as create_date
       count(*) as Book_Count
FROM ...tables here
GROUP BY cast(dbo.book.create_time as date)
ORDER BY create_date;
```

You can get the cumulative sum in SQL Server 2012+ using the cumulative sum function:

```
SELECT cast(dbo.book.create_time as date) as create_date
       count(*) as Book_Count,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by cast(dbo.book.create_time as date) ) as Running_Count
FROM ...tables here
GROUP BY cast(dbo.book.create_time as date)
ORDER BY create_date;
```

In earlier versions, you can do something similar with a correlated subquery or `cross apply`.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can do:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT cast(dbo.book.create_time as date) as create_date
             count(*) as Book_Count
      FROM ...tables here
      GROUP BY cast(dbo.book.create_time as date)
    )
SELECT t.create_date, t.Book_Count,
       (SELECT SUM(Book_Count)
        FROM t t2
        WHERE t2.create_date <= t.create_date
       ) as Running_Count
FROM t
ORDER BY create_date;
```

Comment: however, on the sum function, it says Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: is the edit supposed to give me the count, and running total as 2 columns?

Comment: @user3356789 . . . Yes.

Comment: this looks awesome! In the backend I do have a person_id, and my select query is returning non-distinct person_ids...is there a way to add that to the select query above, so that my counts are correct :)

Comment: figured it out....I did count (distinct person_id) as Book_Count instead! Thank you so much for all your help @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `trunc(book.create_time)` in your query instead of the conversion you're doing